# Wayland surface position

Tags: gnome, wayland, xdotool, display-manager, wmctrl

I know Wayland protocol doesn't provide option to control shell surface position on the screen. I would like to find a way for controlling window/surface placement. I have tried tools like xdotool and wmctrl, but they only recognize XWayland windows. I am using Gnome Shell so the window manager is Mutter. Why is surface location not part of Wayland protocol? What would be the suggested way or ways for controlling Wayland surface placement programmatically?

Edit:

Wayland client-protocol provides interface for sub-surfaces and it is sufficient for my purposes at the moment. However window I would hope protocol to include top-level window position option. I could make gnome-shell extension with, javascript? But not really an option in this case.

Comment: I need the same information. For example, I cannot get title of nautilus, system monitor, video player, etc while they are active on the screen. If somebody knows or  you have found the solution please share it here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Martin are you working with compositor-side or with client-side. At the moment I am working only the client-side.

Comment: I'm working on client-side. FYI, I want to record my activities and I was successful but some applications are not recorded using xdotool. I don't know if the xlib can do it for me to use it. I doubt it.